Why no "Al cheit" in the Neila service?
The Neilah service includes a full Selichot and an almost-complete Vidui, but does not include "Al Cheit..."  Is there a reason for this?

No, it includes a highly abbreviated slichot, abbreviated kedushta, etc.

There are/were many communities that do/did birkat kohanim at ne'ila, and they'd want to get to it before dark.

@magicker72 FWIW there also are/were some communities (germans) that were willing to do it even after dark. But anyway that's not the only reason to try finish before dark: the day is over at dark! The gates are already closed!

@DoubleAA If the day has gone and the gates have closed, why are we approaching the gate - and then following with half a dozen selichos, as well as an Avinu Malkeinu filled with requests for חתמינו?

@Yehuda We don't. Or at least very few of us try to. The vast majority of opinions hold the time for Neilah ends at sunset (or some say nightfall). Shulchan Aruch is explicit אין לו למשוך בתפלת נעילה כל תיבה ותיבה כדרך שמושך בשאר תפלות כדי שיגמור קודם שקיעת החמה The mishna berua says that even though that is the halacha, someone who continues past the end of the time shouldn't be protested against. So my point above that there's good reason to try and finish on time (besides duchening) holds

The rest of Yom Kippur is for thorough and exhaustive prayers. Neilah is the icing on top of the cake whose proper time is only about a half hour around sunset. Accordingly, all the variable components of the prayer (piyyutim, slichot, vidui, etc.) were written concisely and/or later truncated, often dramatically, relative to the other prayers of the day.

(To fully appreciate this, you may have to look at the full services as designed, eg. with all the things in the back of the artscroll machzor put back in place as well as putting back all the things artscroll didn't even bother printing in their appendices.)
